# Is there way to only show the PWA 'Add to Home Screen' on index?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ionic3, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

We have a PWA that works great and the "add to home screen" also works great. The problem is, for users that just want to start using the app, have our primary action button covered by that prompt.

Unless they accept or dismiss the prompt, they wont be able to continue using our app.

What we would prefer is if the user navigates away from the home page towards actually using our PWA, we automatically dismiss the "add to home screen" button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Changes to Add to Home Screen Behavior

Starting in Chrome 68 on Android (Stable in July 2018), Chrome will no longer show the add to home screen banner. If the site meets the add to home screen criteria, Chrome will show the mini-infobar. Then, if the user clicks on the mini-infobar, or you call prompt() on the beforeinstallprompt event from within a user gesture, Chrome will show a modal add to home screen dialog.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/a2hs-updates

Comment: Did you mean 2019? The middle "Mini-infobar" is what we have showing now that we want to hide on sub-pages. Basically we just want to be able to dismiss it on our end.

Comment: As per this post [Changes to Add to Home Screen Behaviour](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/a2hs-updates) you should be able to listen for the **beforeinstallprompt** event and update your user interface as required.

Comment: I am having issues setting up update for my PWA, can you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797611/tying-to-update-pwa-swupdate-isenabled-is-true-but-not-calling-the-subscribed-m