# Tying to update PWA: swUpdate.isEnabled is true but not calling the subscribed method even when ngsw-config.json is altered

Tags: events, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

services/pwa.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SwUpdate } from '@angular/service-worker';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/interval";

@Injectable()
export class PwaService {
  public promptEvent: any;

  constructor(private swUpdate: SwUpdate) {
    alert('swUpdate isEnabled:' + swUpdate.isEnabled);// => alerts true
    if (swUpdate.isEnabled) {
      Observable.interval(10)
                .subscribe(() => swUpdate.checkForUpdate().then(() => alert('checking for swUpdate')));//<= Not triggered
    }
  }

  public checkForUpdates(): void {
    this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(event => this.promptUser());
  }

  private promptUser(): void {
    alert('updating to new version');//<=Not triggered either
    this.swUpdate.activateUpdate()
                .then(() => document.location.reload());
  }
}
```

services/index.ts:

```
providers: [
....
{ provide: SwUpdate, useClass: SwUpdate }
]
```

app.modules.ts:

```
imports: [
....
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
]
providers: [
...
PwaService,
]
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { PwaService } from './services/pwa.service'; 
....
constructor(public Pwa: PwaService) {
  this.Pwa.checkForUpdates();
}
```

ngsw-config.json(just minor change from `lazy` to `prefetch`) to trigger update:

```
....
"installMode": "prefetch",
....
```

Comment: I'm guessing you've tried incognito and getting rid of cached stuff and also set the server to not cache the file? How does your network tab look like, mines consistently checking for ngsw.json, https://snag.gy/8y6cz2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on all devices:

```
export class PwaUpdateService {

    updateSubscription;

    constructor(public updates: SwUpdate) {
    }

    public checkForUpdates(): void {
        this.updateSubscription = this.updates.available.subscribe(event => this.promptUser());

        if (this.updates.isEnabled) {
            // Required to enable updates on Windows and ios.
            this.updates.activateUpdate();

            interval(60 * 60 * 1000).subscribe(() => {
                this.updates.checkForUpdate().then(() => {
                    // console.log('checking for updates');
                });
            });

        }

        // Important: on Safari (ios) Heroku doesn't auto redirect links to their https which allows the installation of the pwa like usual
        // but it deactivates the swUpdate. So make sure to open your pwa on safari like so: https://example.com then (install/add to home)
    }

    promptUser(): void {
        this.updates.activateUpdate().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
        });
    }
}
```